# AngularJS nested Arrays using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been spinning my wheels on this one. Reading through most of the answers on stackoverfolw has helped me understand more about building nested arrays and using .json files. I still cannot figure out what I'm not doing correctly.
I am trying to build a image viewer for my artwork using Angular. I want to create a .json file that will used to "index/category my work" This way I can use Angular to call the files, names and other data to view without all the hard coding img src and such.
Here is a link to [JSFiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHhpTW?p=info) that I have been messing with. I cannot understand how to pull data from the nested array. If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the plunker, Please see. Your json was coming in data object in received output of web service.

```
 $scope.fetchContent = function () {
    $http.get($scope.url).then(function (data){
        $scope.portfolio = data.data;
      });
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GH14vIWzKVSOdA3wI0Bb?p=preview

Comment: Rock on thanks pankaj. Just a question about `data.data`? Why are we creating a prototype for `data`? I know this in jQuery as a prototype is this using the jqLite in AngularJS?